# html5 validation new password and old password

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, passwords

I do password validation with html5, which I found here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/
I have a form for editing a user account, there I give textfield contains the new password and the old password.
If the new password field is not filled in, the data will be stored, and if the new password field filled in the old password field must be filled, then how do I have to provide validation? if the old password in the field given the required attributes, what if the user does not want to change their password ..

here is the form ..

```
<label>New Password</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"
        onchange=" this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers' : '');"
        >
    </div>

    <label>Old Password</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="confirm_hide" id="confirm_hide" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"
        onchange=" this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers' : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.confirm.pattern = this.value; "
        >
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm" placeholder="Password" " pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}"
        onchange=" this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter valid current password' : ''); "
        >
    </div>
```

Comment: I only hope you use this to do a more visual validation. To really validate this form you just need to use php

Comment: @SuperDJ Having a quick look through the linked site, it appears to be solely for checking passwords meet certain complexity criteria - it doesn't handle actual verification of whether one is correct.